# What is the maximum read speed I can get on a MacBook Pro Mid-2015?

Tags: mac, ssd, macbook-pro, pci-express

From what I have [read](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2900330/apple-mac/holy-smoke-the-new-macbook-literally-is-twice-as-fast.html) and being told by [Apple support](https://getsupport.apple.com/), the MacBook Pro mid-2015 has a PCI v3 x4.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express) says that each lane in PCI v3 brings 985 MB/s, so PCI v3 x4 should be 985 * 4 = 3940 MBps (read).

However, I see benchmarks top at 2 GBps, for [example](http://blog.macsales.com/30725-owc-tests-speed-of-ssd-in-2015-15-macbook-pro-with-retina-display):

[image]

Why? Is the limit due to the installed SSD but due not to the PCIe itself? What is the maximum read speed I can get on a MacBook Pro Mid-2015?